# HEC-RAS limitation on cross sections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, flood, limitations, hec-ras

For every cross-section profile, Manning's value is assigned.

There are numerous values in a single cross-section profile but HEC-RAS allows only 20 values per cross-section.

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to input a manning's n value where there is a change. For example the picture below shows a cross section using three manning's n values, but well over three coordinate points.

[image]